# Spring REST - Array inside RequestBody only contains one Element

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, post

This is my first question here, so please do not be too harsh :)

Inside my spring-mvc driven REST backend I created two entities like this:

```
@Entity
public class ObjectWithParameters implements Serializable {

private long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String content;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "service")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Parameter> parameters = new HashSet<Parameter>();

...

public Set<Parameter> getParameters() {
  return parameters;
}

public void setParameters(Set<Parameter> parameters) {
  this.parameters = parameters;
}

...
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Parameter implements Serializable {

private long id;
private String key;
private String value;

@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
private RestService service;

...
```

Inside the @RestController for the *ObjectWithParameters*-Entity I tried creating a @RequestMapping which takes JSON containing an *ObjectWithParameters*-Object with the *parameters*-set inside and create corresponding objects from this (and save it afterwards to the mysql database via hibernate).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/object-with-parameters", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody ObjectWithParameters objectWithParameters) {

    for (Parameter param : objectWithParameters.getParameters()) {
        log.debug("Param inside received ObjectWithParameters: {}", param);
    }

    ...
}
```

The For-Loop only runs one time and if i log or save (or whatever) the parameter set contains only one parameter object... even if the JSON inside the RequestBody looks like this (I checked this with the dev tools in chrome):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "testName",
  "description": "testDescription",
  "content": "testContent",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "value": "foo",
      "key": "bar"
    },
    {
      "value": "foo2",
      "key": "bar2"
    },
    {
      "value": "foo3",
      "key": "bar3"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case the log output from inside the shown for loop will only be

`"01:54:52-800 [DEBUG] ParamInside received ObjectWithParameters: ServiceParameter [id=0, service=Service [id=1, name=testName, ....], key=bar, value=foo]"`

I tried several things but had no luck... :( 
Any ideas whats wrong with this?

Comment: Maybe there is something to fix in the Parameter hashCode()/equals()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions: Looks like you have implemented Parameter.hashCode() and equals() on the Parameter#id instance variable. Because you are creating an object the Parameter#id is set to 0 for all the Parameters. You store them in a Set which will contain only the first Parameter sent because your hashCode equals thinks all those Parameter with id=0 are the same.

Fix hashCode/equals to handle unsaved object or use a List container instead of Set.

Comment: that was exactly the problem! i feel so stupid right now...totally overlooked that, because in the beginning of creating these entities it was a list instead of an set. Thank you! :)